# My Elan touchpad has been detected as both a mouse and a touchpad, and configuration profiles for both types got mingled. How ot fix it?

Tags: touchpad, 22.04, libinput, elantech

When no external mouse is connected, here is the xinput & libinput output respectively:

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Asus Keyboard                             id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN1203:00 04F3:307A Mouse               id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN1203:00 04F3:307A Touchpad            id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Wireless Radio Control               id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Keyboard                             id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Keyboard                             id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Keyboard                             id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

```
$ sudo libinput list-devices
Device:           ELAN1203:00 04F3:307A Mouse
Kernel:           /dev/input/event6
Group:            8
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     pointer 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   *button
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   flat *adaptive
Rotation:         n/a

Device:           ELAN1203:00 04F3:307A Touchpad
Kernel:           /dev/input/event13
Group:            8
Seat:             seat0, default
Size:             101x52mm
Capabilities:     pointer gesture
Tap-to-click:     disabled
Tap-and-drag:     enabled
Tap drag lock:    disabled
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   *two-finger edge 
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: enabled
Accel profiles:   flat *adaptive
Rotation:         n/a
...
```

As a result, sometimes the touchpad will suddenly lose ability to do gestures and 2-finger scrolling, because the mouse takes higher input priority. How to avoid this situation?

Answer (score -1):

Found this works for myself most of the time to restart dead mouse:

added20220806 BTW my current system is Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)

## sudo fwupdtool get-devices

On some occasions it did not work, so ran same command another time or two.

Every now and then it just did not work, so then ordered shutdown reboot, to recover.

.

Comment: This command doesn't do anything useful. It just shows devices that can have firmware upgrade.